# Ambient Occlusion Bake Too Dark On Some Meshes on Blender 2.8

Tags: texturing

I'm new to Blender (2.8) and I'm having issues with baking an ambient occlusion texture onto my UV map.  I'm trying to get an even shade baked across my entire UV map for when I color it.  However, after baking the Ambient Occlusion, certain islands on my UV map are almost completely blackened (the outside of the hat and hair mesh islands in particular).  Why is this happening, and how can I fix the bake such that the ambient occlusion is spread evenly?

Thank you for any insight you can give.

Comment: I recently had a lot of trouble baking AO for a character's teeth. The mouth was open and regular scene renders showed them looking textured correctly, but my AO bakes were completely black or completely transparent. It turned out that my UV coordinates were offset by exactly 4x the UV canvas; I had to move the UV's back inside the canvas. Then suddenly my bake worked. See if there is anything unusual about your UV's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The normals are inverted for those portions of the mesh so it's trying to light it inside out. You just need to view the problem parts, select linked and then flip normals.
The new Blender 2.80 quickest way to indicate which way the normals are pointing is in the Viewport Overlays popover (top right of viewport) - toggle option that says 'Face Orientation'.

[image: screenshot of Viewport Overlays popover with face orientation highlighted]

Comment: That worked, thank you so much!  You are awesome.  I'll keep that in mind moving forward!